# How do I hire a friend?

Tags: ios, we-rule

I'm experimenting with We Rule, but at level 6 I have an objective to:

'Hire your friend'

Now I don't have any friends, so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: +1 because the phrase "Now I don't have any friends" got a twinge of sympathy from me. :/

Comment: that must be the objective, right? You have no friends, so you hire one :)

Comment: How about going to the players tab (or leaderboards, or ranking, or whatever its called) and adding every possible player you see there. I bet at least one of them accepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the jackass answer is find a friend to play the game with. Another idea is if you have Facebook, post a status message asking for anyone who has the game, but that is putting yourself out on Facebook which may not be desirable. You could also find people via the [Facebook We Rule Page](http://www.facebook.com/WeRuleGame) and post on the discussion board there.

Developers put objectives like "Hire your friend' or 'Give a gift to a friend' (a la Farmville) as a marketing and expansion tool. By completing the objective, it expands the game's user base and maximum possible revenue for the developer.

Comment: So I guess I should just 'ignore' it and continue friendless? Unless anyone here plays it ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I signed up two accounts, and made each of them friends

Comment: The actual intention was for the player to be 'alone' until they grew old enough to tell the difference between 'friend' and 'weirdo'

Answer (score 4):

This was my least favorite part of We Rule. Plus, when you finally find a friend and get the objective done, nothing else happens afterwards. That's the last objective to do... It's just plain sandbox after that.

Haven't played in a couple of months, but I do have some job stuff happening. You can add me as a friend if you'd like. My name's `elbaso` in We Rule.